# About vague convergence of distribution functions

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I know the definition of vague convergence as

> **Definition:**
> Let $F_n$ be distribution functions. $F_n\rightarrow F$ if for every finite interval I of continuity points of $F$ $F_n(I)\rightarrow F(I)$.

That is the definition I got from my professor who pointed out that the measure defined by $F$ may not be a probability measure but I can't imagine a counterexample to that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider the measures $\delta_n$ that give mass 1 to set in the real line that contains the point $n$, and mass $0$ otherwise. That is, $\delta_n$ is a probability measure concentrated at $\{n\}$. You can see that the sequence converges to $0$ vaguely.

Comment: so I should show that $\int f d\delta_n$ converges to $0$ for every f continuous with compact support? If that's true I guess the point is that $\int f d\delta_n=f(n)$ but for n going to infinity it converges to 0 because $ f$ is in $C_c$, is that okay?

Comment: That is correct. You can also see that for any set $A$ in the real line $\delta_n(A)=\mathbb{1}_A(n)$; hence, I’d $A$ is a bounded interval, $\delta_n(A)\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: All right| Thanks a lot